# Open Visual Studio project on other device

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

I want to work on my VS project on an other device, just copying the Files didnt work for me.  When i open the project on my secondary device every reference is missing even the system references.

Its an Framework C# Forms project.

[image: using system missing]

Comment: Have you also installed all the external packages on the other device ?

Comment: Can you provide specific error information, which will help analyze and solve the problem.